# Python Regular Expression not match

Tags: python, regex

I want to use python re to match this kind of input:12,13,45,23.

The input is combined by four non-negative integers, separated by ",".

However, my re does not match...

```
 print re.match(u'^([1−9]\d*|0),([1−9]\d*|0),([1−9]\d*|0),([1−9]\d*|0)$',u"0,1001,13,2")
 #output is None
```

However, the next re works well.

```
 print re.match(u'^([1−9]\d*|0),([1−9]\d*|0),([1−9]\d*|0)$',u"0,1001,13")
 #<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x024151B0>
```

I am totally confused.

Comment: @IceArdor the OP obviously doesn't want numbers to start with '0' except for '0' itself... and it doesn't explain the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you don't need to repeat the regex that match each integer, you can use the `{x}` where `x` is  the number of times it should appear, something like:

```
import re

matcher = re.compile(u"([1-9]\d*|0)(,([1-9]\d*|0)){3}$")

print matcher.match(u"12,45")
# None
print matcher.match(u"0,1001,13,578")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fb0e911ca48>
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I still have a question, why you do not use  "^" to match the start of input? If the input is "asdf0,12,13,24", I think your match result will not be None. However, I find your re outputs "None" for this kind input. Can you explain it? Thanks a lot! @Ruben Bermudez

Comment: Check http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match `match` start at the  beginning of the string, it is the `search` option the one that have the problem you suggest.

Comment: I updated my answer as I found a *bug* in my regex, it was written `\d+` but it should be `\d*` so it allows also *one-digit integers*